# Add Action on CCLayer in cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCLayer` class which i'm using for pause menu and inside that class i have menuitems . I've just added menu and it shows on screen but no animation in it. I want to add transition effect on layer as we can do it in scene. or add action as we do in sprite. I just want my pause menu to animate from up to down.

Here how i am adding my `CClayer` class.

```
 menuLayer = [[PauseMenu alloc] initWithParent:self];
 [self addChild:menuLayer z:99];
```

I have tried this code for action but it doesn't work

```
menuLayer = [[PauseMenu alloc] initWithParent:self];
[self addChild:menuLayer z:99];
id move=[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5.1 position:ccp(240,120)];
[menuLayer runAction:move];
```

Comment: I was using [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
before adding menu layer .. now menu is coming from up to down but my game play is not paused. its running in background. do i have to stop it individualy?

Comment: you have adding menu on your layer .. right?  so what is the starting position of your pause menu ?

Comment: In the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment I'll recommend you not to use `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]` pause] as it does not really will pause your game logic (only actions and schedulers) but if you have some thread doing game logic (like moving objects or calculating some stuff) it will still keep running.

If you want to pause your game you should keep an internal state of your game. So for example in your update method you could do :

```
if (gameState == GAME_PAUSE)
   return;
```

This way it will be easy for you to decide what continues to be done and what not until the game returns to play.